# Regexing URLs with and without a protocol in PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I've got this URL regex:

> /(?:((?:[^-/"':!=a-z0-9_@]|^|\:))((https?://)((?:[^\p{P}\p{Lo}\s].-|[^\p{P}\p{Lo}\s])+.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]+)?)(/(?:(?:([a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_,~]+))|@[a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_,~]+/|[.\,]?(?:[a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_~]|,(?!\s)))*[a-z0-9=#/]?)?(\?[a-z0-9!*'();:&=+\$/%#[]-_.,~]*[a-z0-9_&=#/])?))/iux

What it's currently matching:

- http://www.google.com
- http://google.com

I need it to also match:

- www.google.com
- google.com

I tried making the protocol part of the regex optional by slapping a ? at the end "(https?:\/\/)?" but that didn't do anything.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look for something in the language that you are using to do this. URLs are tough to match with a regex. If you insist, I changed yours to make the `(https?://)` optional. I did not check it though.

```
/(?:((?:[^-/"':!=a-z0-9_@]|^|\:))((https?://)?((?:[^\p{P}\p{Lo}\s].-|[^\p{P}\p{Lo}\s])+.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]+)?)(/(?:(?:([a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_,~]+))|@[a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_,~]+/|[.\,]?(?:[a-z0-9!*';:=+\$/%#[]-_~]|,(?!\s)))*[a-z0-9=#/]?)?(\?[a-z0-9!*'();:&=+\$/%#[]-_.,~]*[a-z0-9_&=#/])?))/iux
```

I got this example from [the RFC 3986](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#page-51) and was directed there by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/161779#161779). Although, I'd still recommend using something from whatever language you are using rather than a regex.

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

Since you are using PHP, did you consider using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)? It looks like it will return false on bad urls.

Comment: Already mentioned in my post that making the (https?://) optional doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: I missed that, but it worked for me. What language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: Actually, appending a ? there fixed it. I had some code further down that was ignoring protocol-less URLs. Thanks!